# ayuda, intento actualizar seleccionando un valor de un spinner el cual los quiero eliminar por medio de su id

Tags: android-studio

Lo que  intento es seleccionar un valor del spinner y en el edittext  poner la actualización. Esto ya  lo realiza  pero no con el valor que estoy seleccionando, me actualiza el valor con un id antes del que yo estoy seleccionando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   // ACTUALIZAR FAMILIA
  private void submitForm() {
    int type = 
 Integer.parseInt(spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItem().toString());
    ActualizarFamilia(
            spbuscarfamilia.getItemIdAtPosition(type),
            etmodificacion.getText().toString());
 }

private void ActualizarFamilia(final long id, final String familia) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";
    showLoadingDialog("Espere Actualizando ......");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_UPDATE_FAMILIA, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado = jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this," Actualización  en Familia  con  éxito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast1.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);;
                    toast1.show();
                    Limpiar();
                } else {
                    hideLoadingDialog();
                    Toast toast2= Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this,"No 
se Actualizó  por que no existe  Familia con este Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=
 (TextView)toast2.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                    Limpiar();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast toast3=  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            toast3.show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", String.valueOf(id));
            params.put("familia",familia);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}


public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(texto);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }

}

public void hideLoadingDialog() {
    try {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception a) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Sofia. ¿Y que problema tienes? Has de explicar que te esta sucediendo. Has mirado logs o debug ? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b  acabo de  agregar  mi  código  para actualizar un registro seleccionado de un spinner. Mi  problema  es  que  si actualiza el registro  que yo deseo  actualizar. lo malo que el logcat no me  marca error. Espero  puedas  ayudarme.

Comment: Sofia, has añadido mucho codigo pero no lo esencial que es explicar qué te sucede y ponerlo en los comentarios no es lo adecuado. Ha de quedar toda la informacion relevante en la pregunta.  Da más informacion y ejemplos. Intenta crear logs más concienzudos o usa el modo debug. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, acabo de  mejorar mi pregunta. Espero  puedas  ayudarme.Saludos